# Google Apps Calendar shows "Busy" instead of sharing full, more details

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-apps

We're building a multi-user platform where each registered user has a Google App account with their e-mail and calendar.

People can add to the events to the calendar, but the entry always show "Busy" instead of displaying the full event details.

How do I get the calendar to share and show more than just "Busy" and list the event name?

Comment: When I create an event through the Calendar UI, I can set the "privacy" level to "private," "public," or "default." The default is controlled in the general Calendar settings. I assume you're using the Calendar API. Doesn't the API expose such a parameter?

Answer (score 20):

First log into your Google Apps domain admin account.  The organization admin url is `https://google.com/a/yourdomainname.com`

Go to Apps > Calendar > Sharing Settings or here (substitute your domain):
https://admin.google.com/yourdomainname.com/AdminHome?fral=1#AppDetails:service=Calendar

Choose **Share all information, but outsiders cannot change calendars**
[image: Organization calendar sharing settings]

Then log into the user account with the calendar.

The new setting took 5 minutes before it took affect on the user accounts.  I logged out and back in a couple times, refreshed, etc.  Eventually the Calendar share settings on the user accounts will allow you to **change the default "See only free/busy (hide details)" choice to "See all event details"** and you're done.

[image: User account calendar sharing settings]

Comment: If this does not work for you it might be because of what @Gary Ogasawara posted below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13144108/37526

Answer (score 4):

Here's an updated link that sets the Calendar sharing option.
This must be done at the organization-wide level by an administrator.

Options are

Only free/busy information (hide event details): Users can allow people outside your domain to know when they are busy or available, but event details are hidden. Private addresses are hidden from users' calendars.

Share all information, but outsiders cannot change calendar: Users can share their calendar information with people outside your domain. This includes guest list, location, and description. Private addresses are hidden from users' calendars.

Share all information, and outsiders can change calendars: Users can fully share their calendar information with people outside your domain. This includes guest list, location, and description. Private addresses are displayed.

Share all information, and allow managing of calendar: Users can fully share their calendar information with people outside your domain, and they can grant outsiders permission to manage their calendars. Private addresses are displayed.

http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=60765

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the "Only free/busy information" option DOES NOT WORK in Google Apps :( When this option is selected at the domain and calendar level events are still not shown in the calendar. Very frustrating.

Comment: When I'm logged in as an organization user I see event details but once I log out the embedded calendar changes to only show "Busy".  Did you try logging out and testing the shared calendar?

Comment: With an Apps account you can actually call Google and a person will get on the phone and fix issues.  I just used their phone support last week.

Comment: Hot dang! I'll do that.