# Google Calendar API: When accessing domain users' calendar, AccessRole is always FreeBusyReader

Tags: .net, oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api, service-accounts

I am trying to read a users calendar with a service account. The calendar of the user is shared with the service account with AccessRole "reader". However when I open the calendar of any user it is always opened as "FreeBusyReader":

First I am adding the user into the calendar list (I had the impression that it is working better when it is in the list, no idea if this is really needed):

```
Dim Calendar As CalendarListEntry
Calendar = service.CalendarList().Insert("user@domain.com").Execute()
```

Then I am checking the access role with:

```
Calendar.AccessRole
```

And it always returns "FreeBusyReader".

This does also match the results in the request afterwards:

```
Dim requeust As ListRequest = service.Events.List("<email address>")
requeust.MaxResults = 99
requeust.TimeMin = DateTime.Now.ToString(dateFormat)
requeust.TimeMax = DateTime.Now.AddDays(fetchtimespan).ToString(dateFormat)
requeust.ShowDeleted = True
requeust.SingleEvents = True
```

is returning a list of entries, but without the summary, and the events list does also have the same AccessRole.

What I did on the user is sharing the calendar with the service users e-mail address (xxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com), I did also verify that via the API.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you referring to `CalendarList`? Based on the Calendar API documentation,[ `Calendar`](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendars#resource-representations) resource doesn't have `accessRole` but [`CalendarList`](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList#resource) resource does. Service Account shouldn't be an issue regarding the data being returned.

Comment: Yes, you are right, CalendarList does not have it, but CalendarListEntry, which is returned by the first line of code (I will change it to make it clear).

Comment: Look at this post it might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1488453/google-apps-calendar-shows-busy-instead-of-sharing-full-more-details

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I will check that.